# Retrain image classifier using MobileNet v2

Tags: overfitting, inception

I am using my own dataset to retrain mobilenet_v2_100_224 model, I currently have 4 classes where each class have more than 100 images still I'm observing overfitting even though I've used `--random_scale` and `--random_brightness` parameters, how should I overcome this overfitting problem when there's no such regularization technique available in the [retrain.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py) script? following is my TensorBoard visualization:

**Retrain command:**

```
python retrain.py --tfhub_module https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/mobilenet_v2_100_224/feature_vector/2 --how_many_training_steps 500 --random_scale=5 --random_brightness=10 --output_graph=./retrained_graph.pb --output_labels=./retrained_labels.txt --image_dir ./data --summaries_dir /tmp/log
```

[image]

Comment: How many images do you have? If your dataset is small you will always suffer from overfitting if you train long enough.

Comment: Currently have 4 classes where each class have more than 100 images.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see any overfitting there. Overfitting is when your validation loss becomes worse with time, while training loss improves. Just because your training error is less than the validation (which is expected) does not mean it overfits.

But you can try to freeze the first layers (up to the fully connected one) to ensure the network does not lose generalization.

Comment: The problem is it's doing worst on generalization and hence I'm getting very poor results in predictions.

Comment: I agree with @Dmytro that these graphs don't look like a over-fitting case. You probably not able to learn the patterns since you have about 400 images to train. Try applying some data augmentation, that will probably improve your accuracy